# How to Change .getMergedRanges() From String to a Range?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

The following code will run very slow in my Google Sheets because my getRange is too large. Is there a way to only loop through the columns that are merged? I only want the for loop to get the number of columns in "yourRange" that are merged.

```
function getUpfrontCosts() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LPB_COST');
    var cl , count=0;
    var yourRange = sheet.getRange("H13:UV13");
    for (var i = 1; i < yourRange.getNumColumns()+1; i++)
    {
        cl=yourRange.getCell(1, i);
        if (cl.isPartOfMerge()){
            if (cl.offset(15, 0).getBackground() == "#ff8300" && cl.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1, 1).getValue()=='Upfront Costs') {
               count = count + cl.offset(15, 0).getValue();
            }
            else {
            }   
        } else {
        }
    }
   return count;
};
```

The second code is how I am trying to turn a string to a range. I am getting "Cell reference out of range" error

How can I change cl to not be a string and be a range?

```
function getUpfrontCosts() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('LPB_COST');
    var destSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Top Level PN');
    var cl , count=0;
    var yourRange = sheet.getRange("I13:UZ13");
    var mergedRanges = yourRange.getMergedRanges();
    for (var i = 0; i < mergedRanges; i++){
    }
    var newRange = sheet.getRange(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation());
    Logger.log(newRange.getA1Notation());
    for (var i = 0; i < newRange.getNumColumns()+1; i++){
      cl=newRange.getCell(1, i);
      Logger.log(newRange.getA1Notation());
          if (cl.offset(15, 0).getBackground() == "#ff8300" && cl.getValue()=='Upfront Costs') {
               count = count + cl.offset(15, 0).getValue();
            }
            else {
            }
    }
   return count;
};
```

**This is the line with the error**

```
   cl=newRange.getCell(1, i);
```

Comment: Use https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#getMergedRanges() . Then you can use `Range#offset` to get ranges that span multiple rows in those same columns.

Comment: Use getMergedRanges()

Comment: hi user11982798, I just posted a second code using getMergedRanges and it isn't working, going to go back and test more

Comment: cl is  a string not a range.  Look at your code carefully ask yourself what type is being returned

Comment: I keep trying and am still not getting the same answer as i should be getting. Can someone please guide me with what I am doing that is different?

Comment: "here is my attempt" is not helpful. What issues do you have? error messages? Incorrect results? Example sheet config? Your comments say you want to get the count of columns, but then you actually use the value of a cell...

Comment: .getMergedRanges says it returns a range, why is it returning a string?

Comment: var newRange = sheet.getRange(mergedRanges[i].getA1Notation()), so newRange  is string because you get getA1Notation() from merge range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use merge cell range, you can do this:

```
function UntitledMacro1() 
{
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
    var cl , count=0 ;
    var yourRange = sheet.getRange("I13:UZ13");
    var bb = yourRange.getMergedRanges();
    for (a=bb[0].getColumn();a<bb[0].getLastColumn()+1;a++)
    {
      //Your actual columns from I13, for first merge range, here your cl, 
      //but if your range is ("13:13"), you don't need 
      //-sheet.getRange("I13").getColumn()+1
      cl=yourRange.getCell(1, a-sheet.getRange("I13").getColumn()+1);

      //For your offset 15
      Logger.log(cl.offset(15, 0).getValue());

      //on so on

    }
};
```